# Data table overlaps footer when printing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

So my table with a lot of data overlaps my footer on my print page, how do i make when the data is about to reach the footer the remaining data will go to the second page, here is the ss:

here you can see that the table with data overlaps my footer(starting with the "NOTE:")

[image]

here is my code for the footer:

```
     <div class="divFooter" style="display:block;position:absolute;width:100%;bottom:0px;">
      <div class="row" style="font-size:12px;"><div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="width:100%;height:20px;border-top:1px solid #E8E8E8;border-bottom:1px solid #E8E8E8;background:color:"><p style="margin-left:10px;">NOTE:</p> </div>
            <div style="height:100%;width:50%;border-right:1px solid #E8E8E8;float:left;">
```

sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h6y4srez/

Comment: you have fix height..change to auto and you are done.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/h6y4srez/3/

Comment: does not work when printing the footer goes down to the second page

Comment: check my fiddle.. i have used clear:both and removed fix height.. please share full code as in above code i have fixed that.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/j25JE the same thing happen when i try to print the footer doesn't stay on the first page to act as a footer

Answer (score 1):

Quick question regarding this table.

The footer you have coded. It seems to be entirely related in subject to that of the main body of the table. Is this correct?

If so, can you simply not put the end part within a `<tfoot>` tag, thus joining it to the table proper and preventing it from running over any other content?

Comment: i don't have any <tfoot> tag, the footer i made is a <div> tag to separate it from the table but when i fix or absolute the footer the data table just doesn't care and overlaps the footer

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS:

```
thead, tfoot { display: table-row-group }
```

This makes them render as normal rows, without attempting to repeat them when there is a page break.