# Overlapping text when repeating footer in Datatable (plugin) in print mode A4

Tags: html-table, datatables, overlapping

I am using Datatable plugin for creating table and i have an issue when i want to print the table in A4 format. The problem is with my footer that is overlapping with the table body. Is there any way to solve this issue? 
Just for note when i print the table in Letter format then my footer looks fine.

I found this question posted on stack overflow ([Data table overlaps footer when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581726/data-table-overlaps-footer-when-printing)), but there is no answer that is solving my problem. My overlapping is happening when printing in A4 format.

```
<table class="display nowrap table-responsive" style="width:100%; overflow-x: scroll; display: block" data-order='[[ 0, "asc" ]]'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

```
extend: 'print',
autoprint: 'false',
footer: 'true',
customize: function (win) {
    var tFoot = win.document.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
    var footerTitle = $(tFoot.children[0].children[0]);
    footerTitle.html('<b>Printed on: ' + moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss') + '</b>');

    tFoot.style.position = 'fixed'
    tFoot.style.bottom = 0;
    tFoot.style.display = 'table-footer-group';
```